# Time ordering of normal ordered product

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, wick-theorem

I would like to calculate $$<0|T(:x^4::y^4:)|0>$$ for scalar fields $x$, $y$ "by hand", but I don't understand yet how. With Wicks theorem I'd say this is strictly 0. Is this correct?

By hand I will get, also using Wicks theorem, $$T(...) = : :x^4::y^4: + permutations * D_F(x-y) * :x^3::y^3: + ... :.$$ However, I don't understand how to determine the number of permutations in this case, especially since the number of permutations for the terms with higher powers in the D_F seems to decrease due to topological equivalence. How do I have to understand this? Whenever I plug in the normal ordered product by hand I have the impression I should get way more commutators than there are supposed to be, but I just don't get what exactly I am missing here.